# How do I use rule in another rule in prolog

Tags: prolog

Here are my facts:

```
object('Human').
object('Machine').
object('Robot').
object('Hunter').
object('WallE').

action('Kill').
action('Run').

rel1('Hunter', 'Human').
rel1('Robot', 'Machine').
rel1('WallE', 'Robot'). 

rel2('Human', 'Run').
rel2('Machine', 'Run').
rel2('Robot', 'Kill').
```

I'm trying to find the list of all object that implement a given action. So for example if I run this:

```
?-provides_action(’Run’, X).
```

It gives the result:
`X = [’Human’, ’Machine’, ’Hunter’, ’Robot’, ’WallE’].`
OR

```
?-provides_action(’Kill’, X).
```

It gives the result:

```
X = ['WallE'].
```

I have tried this

```
provides_action2(X, L) :- findall(Y, (rel2(Y,X)),L).
provides_action3(X, L) :- provides_action2(X, L1), findall(Z, rel1(Z,L1), L2), append(L1,L2,L).
```

It doesnt give me the correct answer, I want to use the result from the first rule (L1) and use it in the 2nd findall extends(Z,L1) but it doesnt seem to do that.

Could anyone please explain to me what's wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have no definition of `extends/2`, for one. This is probably the subclass relationship written as `rel1/2` in the first code block?

Comment: Yes sorry, you are right it is supposed to be rel1. I edited the code. Basically I am trying to use the L1 (result of the fist provide_action2) as one of the attribute in the rel1(Z, L1), L2.
but it doesnt work as I wanted it to, is there any other way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must define predicate `extends/2` using `rel1/2`:

```
extends(A, C) :- rel1(A, C).
extends(A, C) :- rel1(A, B), extends(B, C).
```

Examples:

```
?- extends(X, 'Human').
X = 'Hunter' ;
false.

?- extends(X, 'Machine').
X = 'Robot' ;
X = 'WallE' ;
false.
```

After, you can use this predicate to define `provides_action/2`, as following:

```
provides_action(X, L) :-
   findall(Y, rel2(Y,X), L1),
   findall(C, (member(A, L1), extends(C, A)), L2),
   append(L1, L2, L).
```

Notice that `member(A, L1)` is needed to iterate  list `L1`.

Running example:

```
?- provides_action('Run', L).
L = ['Human', 'Machine', 'Hunter', 'Robot', 'WallE'].
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, I just edited the original question, there is no extends rule. I made a mistake in the question it is supposed to be rel1 instead. The whole query I had is this:
provides_action3(X, L) :- provides_action2(X, L1), findall(Z, rel1(Z,L1), L2), append(L1,L2,L).

Comment: I think you cannot solve the problem without predicate ```extends/2```, since relation ```rel1/2``` does not relate ```'WallE'``` to ```'Machine'``` directly. See:  ```rel1('WallE', 'Robot')``` and ```rel1('Robot', 'Machine')```.